# Missing Right Parenthesis Error in an AND NOT EXISTS when joining?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

Kind of stumped. Calling a few AND NOT EXISTS and the one I have a join in keeps giving me the "Missing right Parenthesis" Error and sending the error cursor to the J in JOIN. Any assistance would be great! Thanks

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gift g 
  WHERE g.gift_donor_id = xc5.id_number
    AND g.gift_associated_amount + g.gift_associated_credit_amt > 0
 JOIN primary_gift pg ON pg.prim_gift_receipt_number = g.gift_receipt_number
                     AND pg.prim_gift_source_of_info = 'AW')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously just a portion of your code, but I can see right now that your are missing a right parenthesis between lines 3 and 4:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gift g 
  WHERE g.gift_donor_id = xc5.id_number
    AND g.gift_associated_amount + g.gift_associated_credit_amt > 0
) -- <== This one was missing.
 JOIN primary_gift pg ON pg.prim_gift_receipt_number = g.gift_receipt_number
                     AND pg.prim_gift_source_of_info = 'AW')
```

That or you need to rearrange it like this:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM gift g 
      JOIN primary_gift pg
        ON pg.prim_gift_receipt_number = g.gift_receipt_number
       AND pg.prim_gift_source_of_info = 'AW'
     WHERE g.gift_donor_id = xc5.id_number
       AND g.gift_associated_amount + g.gift_associated_credit_amt > 0)
```

So that the join comes before the where clause.

Comment: Fairly certain that the second proposition is correct since in the first, unless I am mistaken, the `g` alias in `g.gift_receipt_number` wouldn't be known outside the parentheses.

Comment: That all depends on the rest of the query that isn't shown.  The existence check could be part of a join condition for table xc5 which joins to another table aliased g above it.